# Как преобразовать строки в словарь?

Tags: python, словари

как из строк вида <name>\t<vasya> создать словарь с ключем name и значение vasya?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = '<name>\t<vasya>'
>>> print dict([[x[1:-1] for x in s.split('\t')], ])
{'name': 'vasya'}
```

Так?